# problems loading geepack in Mac

Tags: r

I want to run GEE procedure using R but I can't load geepack on my Mac.  Here's the error I got.  Would someone please help me interpret what this means?  Why should I need to load so many other packages in order to use geepack. Thank you.

```
> library(geepack)
Loading required package: doBy
Loading required package: survival
Loading required package: splines
Loading required package: R2HTML
Loading required package: multcomp
Loading required package: mvtnorm
Loading required package: lme4
Loading required package: Matrix
Loading required package: lattice

Attaching package: 'Matrix'

The following object(s) are masked from 'package:base':

    det


Attaching package: 'lme4'

The following object(s) are masked from 'package:stats':

    AIC, BIC

Loading required package: snow
Error: package 'snow' could not be loaded
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package 'survival' was built under R version 2.13.2 
2: In library(pkg, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE, lib.loc = lib.loc) :
  there is no package called 'snow'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the R.2.13.2 version and installed the older version R 2.11 and it worked just fine.  I think the R.2.13.2 version probably needs some fix.  Perhaps the R2.14 version might work better.

Answer (score 2):

The error message seems clear enough. You haven't installed package 'snow'.

Comment: Further, if you had bothered to look at the cran page for geepack, you'd have seen that it depends on doBy, which in turn depends on snow.  Lots of packages have dependencies; this is a good thing as it avoids re-writing and re-compiling tons of code.  I would also point out that one error message makes it clear you are using an old version of R (< 2.13).  You should upgrade before worse things happen.  snow itself requires >2.12.1 .

Comment: Thank you for your tips. I am very new to R thus might need further explanation.  I looked up the internet and thought the version that I downloaded R 2.13.2 for Mac is the latest version.  What else needs to be upgraded? I will try downloading snow package to see if this solves my problem